# tsfresh extract_features runtime error "freeze_support"

Tags: python, time-series, feature-extraction

I recently installed the `tsfresh` package to extract features of my timeseries data. I tried to run the example in the [documentation](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/tsfresh.feature_extraction.html#tsfresh.feature_extraction.settings.ComprehensiveFCParameters) and got the following error:

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

I'm a bit confused since it's literally the example code:

```py
from tsfresh.examples import load_robot_execution_failures
from tsfresh import extract_features

df, _ = load_robot_execution_failures()
X = extract_features(df, column_id='id', column_sort='time')
```

I get the same error when i try the function with my own data.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think [there is](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/issues/364) a solution to the problem.
You can try to add `if __name__ == "__main__:"` around function callings.